# Probability for dependent events and "Or"

Tags: probability

Is there a way to calculate the "or" of dependent events?
That is if P(A) = 0.25 and P(B) = 0.6
and P(A|B) = 0 and P(B|A) = 0

I know I can calculate P(A and B) = P(A|B) * P(B)

Is there some way to calculate P(A or B)?

Comment: You know that $P(A \cap B) = 0$ so  you must have $P(A \cap B^c) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \text{ and } B)$$

And you know how to get $P(A \text{ and } B)$.

Answer (score 2):

The probability is 
$$P(A)+P(B)-P(A\mbox{ and }B)=P(A)+P(B)$$
since the events are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

P(A or B) is P(A)+P(B)-P(A and B)

or P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P( B | A )